# How to track app work for all pages without client time?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, dependency-injection

I want to track app work time and this variable could be able for all my components, I know solution with using store, but in this case i will have rerender every second when this variable was updated, so, can u please provide some solution for this case ? I need this app time for all request in my app, but I can't use Date.now() couse this solution based on client time and there can be wrong, my aim is get current time when I make request. From the start my app I fetching time from another server and I want to increment this value every second. Also I could has access for this value in every request, for request I use redux toolkit query.

Answer (score 0):

To track the app's work time and have access to this value in every request without causing re-renders every second, you can use a combination of Redux and a separate timer that updates the time independently of React's rendering cycle.

Here's a step-by-step guide on how to implement this:

1. Set up your Redux store: Create a Redux store using Redux Toolkit to manage the app's work time.
2. Create a separate timer: Use JavaScript's `setInterval` function to create a timer that updates the app's work time every second. This timer will be independent of React's rendering cycle, so it won't trigger re-renders in your components.
3. Use Redux middleware: Implement a Redux middleware that intercepts your API requests and adds the current work time as a header or a parameter to each request.

Here's an example implementation:

Step 1: Set up your Redux store

```
// store.js
import { configureStore, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const timeSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'time',
  initialState: 0, // Initial value is set to 0, update this value with the time fetched from the server at the start of your app
  reducers: {
    updateTime: (state, action) => {
      return action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { updateTime } = timeSlice.actions;

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    time: timeSlice.reducer,
    // other reducers...
  },
});

export default store;
```

Step 2: Create a separate timer

```
// Timer.js
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { updateTime } from './store';

const Timer = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const updateAppTime = () => {
    const currentTime = Date.now(); // Get the current time from the server or an accurate time source
    dispatch(updateTime(currentTime));
  };

  // Update the app time every second
  setInterval(updateAppTime, 1000);

  return null; // We don't need to render anything, so return null
};

export default Timer;
```

Step 3: Use Redux middleware to add the app time to each API request

You can use Redux middleware, specifically `redux-toolkit/query` middleware, to intercept each API request and add the app's work time to it.

```
// api.js
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const baseUrl = 'https://api.example.com'; // Replace with your API base URL

export const api = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    // Define your API endpoints here
    // Example:
    getUsers: builder.query({
      query: () => '/users',
      transformResponse: (response) => response.data,
    }),
  }),
  // Add middleware to intercept API requests and modify headers or parameters
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat((api) => (next) => (action) => {
      const appTime = useSelector((state) => state.time);
      const updatedAction = {
        ...action,
        headers: {
          ...action.headers,
          'X-App-Time': appTime, // Add the app time as a custom header
        },
        // You can also add the app time as a parameter if required
        // params: {
        //   ...action.params,
        //   appTime,
        // },
      };
      return next(updatedAction);
    }),
});

export const { useGetUsersQuery } = api;
```

Finally, wrap your entire app with the Redux store provider and include the `Timer` component to start the app time tracking:

```
// index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';
import Timer from './Timer';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Timer />
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

With this setup, the app's work time will be independently updated every second, and you can access this value in any request using the Redux middleware, without causing unnecessary re-renders in your components.

Comment: the setinterval never guarantees that the passed callback will be called exactly after the passed time, it all depends on the processor load and many other factors, we will run into an error for sure (and I need exactly the time to seconds), well, this is half the trouble, then there is that when using the store, I will be in all places where I make requests to subscribe to the change of the store, I have a lot of such places and it turns out that almost the entire interface will be redrawn every second